# Occasional BSOD with varying error codes

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod

Recently, I've started to get BSOD's- one every few days or so. I've already run all of the disk checking I could find, as well as a memtest, and everything has come up clear. I started collecting the minidumps recently, but as far as I can tell, they're all leading in different directions.

They don't happen when doing anything in particular. More have happened when playing games than when not playing games, but they still happen pretty randomly. My computer has no OEM crap-ware on it, and has been stable until recently. I've checked for driver updates and BIOS updates, but even after updating a few things that had newer versions available, there's still no change.
I've searched for relevant information for all of the error codes I've gotten, but nothing has really helped.

I don't know how to upload the minidumps, but here are three of them analyzed with windbg: https://pastebin.com/gmaND4ue https://pastebin.com/hPRJbfd6 https://pastebin.com/eZNzA4Kg

OS: Windows 10 1803
Hardware: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/cHxfzY
Error codes: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE, BAD POOL HEADER, SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION

Comment: If minidumps would be helpful, please do tell me how to upload them here. I've collected five or six so far, with three or four different error codes.

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem is when memory or CPU are set to too high frequency/bus. First check MemTest86+ for test number 8 which gives most of the errors, then if it is ok - set the nominal frequencies for CPU and memory and see if it helps. Earlier memory errors could modify files when installing Windows so you could have already bugged files on the system disk. A reinstall could be needed. Please check the above and we will see if we can arrange some other way to fix this problem.

Comment: I will try that when I get a chance. My motherboard was unclear on whether or not 3200 MHz (RAM) was considered "overclocked." It listed different "OC" frequencies by CPU series. Should I drop my RAM to 2933 MHz? 
(CPU is at stock speed.)

Comment: @jlc well it depends. If the memory is able to work at 3200 MHz so it should. But if the mobo tells you it is OC then, so you may want to try both solutions and check which one is working properly. Starting with higher frequency to reject it first.

Comment: Should I run MemTest86+ or MemTest86? MemTest86+ does not list support for Pinnacle Ridge (or any recent AMD chip).

Comment: @jlc Surely run the compatible one.

Comment: So if it fails, I guess I should drop to 2933 MHz and try again. But if it passes... then what? I don't particularly want to mess with my CPU's clock speeds.  
And if I eventually have to reinstall, can I do it without losing all of my installed programs? (not documents, those are easy)

Comment: Oh, and I would just replace the problematic system file, but I don't think it's listed any single file twice so far. (Replacement works fine for winlogon.exe... long story)

Comment: @jlc I don't want to take you through all the theory here. Just do what has been said and act accordingly.

Comment: Ok, it passed. All 13 tests, no errors. Now what?

Comment: @jlc that means that CPU and memory are fine so you shouldn't be getting BSODs. Locked at this frequency reinstall Windows. Make a backup first!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91016/discussion-between-jlc-and-pbies). ...I didn't know that generated a message.